# List visualization

Tags: backbone.js, graphics, kendo-ui, game-engine

My last question was all over the place and was closed, so I am asking a more focused single question:
I want to start a website for a task, collaboration and critique application for authors and editors. This will be pure JS client with backbone and KendoUI. Instead of a list view of scenes, I want to tag author beats/scenes and visualize them in the dashboard as the welcome page after login (something like colored 3D bouncing balls that have the tagged text from the scene). I am familiar with C# and Java.

What graphics client technology should I use for the visualization I described? The simpler the better and it would be a plus if I could reuse this later with a mobile app. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using kendo ui why not use their data visualization components? http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx

If that is not your speed you can use a library like http://d3js.org or http://nvd3.org/ with backbone directly.

Comment: Thank you much Scott! I will check those out. Did not realize Kendo had that option either. I will give others a chance to chime in before marking you as answered. Btw these seem web options. What would the equivalent for a iPhone app be?

Comment: Since you mentioned c# you could check out monotouch http://xamarin.com/monotouch with whatever c# visualization lib you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Scott! I have marked your response as answered. I researched Xamarin, it's unclear to me what a equivalent visualization library on the mobile side would be. Perhaps you would like to suggest one? Btw I love your suggestion of d3js for web.

Comment: http://www.steema.com/tags/monotouch & http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/brent_schooley/archive/2012/11/06/getting-started-using-nuclios-with-monotouch-part-1-igchartview.aspx